Inheriting from Python dataclass
I started using data classes recently and am having some issues understanding how inheritance works. I can't understand the problem with too many variables being passed on. Am I using the super() method correctly here?
Attaching code below:
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class ZooAnimals():
    myrange = list(range(10, 16, 1))

    food_daily_kg: Optional[int]
    price_food: float 
    area_required: list = field(default_factory=list)
    name: str = field(default='Zebra', kw_only=True)
    weight: InitVar[int] = field(default = 50, kw_only=True)
    weight_pounds: int = field(init=False)
    dangerous_animal_warning: str = field(default='No', kw_only=True, init=False)
        
    def __post_init__(self, weight):
      
        self.weight_pounds = self.weight * 2.7
        if self.name == 'Crocodile':
            self.dangerous_animal_warning = "Dangerous"

@dataclass
class Cats(ZooAnimals):
    def __init__(self, area_required, name, weight):
        super().__init__(area_required, name, weight)
        
        
        
    
z = Cats([30], name='Leopard', weight=35)
z

Cats(food_daily_kg=[30], price_food='Leopard', area_required=35, name='Zebra', weight_pounds=135.0, dangerous_animal_warning='No')


What is 565 in  Cats(565, area_required = [30], name='Leopard', weight=35) supposed to represent?

In ZooAnimals, your name and weight fields are defined as keyword-only - but in Cats.__init__(), you are passing them positionally in the super() call.  That's not going to work.

There is no reason to implement Cats.__init__, all you do is call the superclass __init__ (in this case, incorrectly), so it really doesn't make sens to do it in the first place, and the simplest fix would be simply not to implement it

Notwithstanding other problems mentioned in previous comments, you pass 565 as positional argument, and it is accepted as area_required (i.e. first after self - the instance object being passed implicitly). Then you pass area_required as keyword argument (that is the second time)

@Mark changed it now, 565 is daily food.

@juanpa.arrivillaga the code is working now, I have fixed the issues. I wanted to follow up on your answer though. You're saying there's no need to have def init in the child class at all, just the line with super, is that correct? Could you post what that would look like?

@user4718221: No, they're saying to remove the method entirely, not to inline it into the class body.

@user4718221 no. I'm saying having an __init__ that just calls the super class __init__ is pointless, and that you should remove the method entirely.

So, can you explain why you decided to implement __init__ inside the Cat class? What do you think is the purpose it serves?

No, it does not work. It may not raise errors, but it does not work right. Does price_food='Leopard' look right to you?
